# How do I manage the basic Azure AD features of a B2C directory?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-active-directory

I need to perform basic administrative functions against an Azure AD B2C instance. For example, I need to adjust the password policy. I can probably do this through PowerShell. However, can I do this trough the portal.azure.com application instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at this moment, let's hope the B2C team releases this quickly, so you don't have to use the Graph API for this anymore.

Comment: We decided to go another direction.